# Yahoo Weather API call using Oauth C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, api, oauth, yahoo

I'm unable to authenticate with Yahoo weather service API via the following code.
What am I doing wrong? I'm getting 401 - Unauthorized. Tried via xml.weather.yahoo.com - same thing. I've been breaking my head with this for a while now, so any help will be appreciated.

CODE:

```
    Public Function getData() As String
    Dim resp As String = ""
    Try
        Dim consumerKey As String = "MY PRIVATE API KEY STRING GOES HERE"
        Dim consumerSecret As String = "SECRET WAS PLACED HERE"
        Dim uri = New Uri("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.bylocation%20WHERE%20location%3D%27Kefar-Weradim%27%20AND%20unit%3D%22c%22&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
        Dim url As String, param As String
        Dim oAuth = New OAuthBase()
        Dim nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce()
        Dim timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp()
        Dim signature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(uri, consumerKey, consumerSecret, String.Empty, String.Empty, "GET", timeStamp, nonce, OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, url, param)
        Using _webResponse As WebResponse = WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", url, param, signature)).GetResponse()
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(_webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                resp = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        resp = "Error: " & ex.Message
    End Try
    Return resp
End Function
```

Comment: I see strange behavior from yahoo api site. With similar code my code returns 401 - Unauthorized in ~80% cases. In ~10% cases it gets me the data. (the rest 10% is for other random failures)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've solved this myself.
The solution is a bit different and doesn not require authentication. What I and many others were trying to do is to get the "weather by location" to work after Yahoo changed their authentication policy. However, "weather forecast" does not require this. So, here's the workaround for the problem above.

```
     Private Function GetDSfromYH() As DataSet
    Dim surl As String = ""
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sbResult As New StringBuilder
    Try
        'surl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/public/v1/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.bylocation%20WHERE%20location%3D%27Kefar-Weradim%27%20AND%20unit%3D%22c%22&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"'
        surl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D1967578%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
        ds.ReadXml(surl)
        Return ds

    Catch ex As Exception
        sbResult.Append("<div>Exception in function 'GetDSfromYH': " & ex.Message & " </div>")
        sbResult.Append("<div style='max-width: 200px;'>Oops, there is a problem with the service. Please refresh the page or try later.</div>")
        divResults.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(sbResult.ToString()))
    End Try


End Function
```

As you can see, I left the old URL string commented out for reference.
The new URL string contains a different approach, with weather.forecast method being summoned and with the use of WOID.
You can locate yours [here](http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/).
Important: there is no need to use any methods to encode the url before sending it. You can use it "As-Is".
The URL used in my function contains celsius at %20u%3D%27c%27 section, with "u" as Units and "c" as celsius. You can replace "c" with "f" if needed.
The function returns a DataSet containing all the parts of the forecast - each as it's own datatable, which you can use as you need.
Good luck friends.